# Defer non-critical CSS in Liquid for Shopify

Tags: php, html, css, shopify, liquid

I'm trying to improve my web performance speed by deferring my CSS and JS. I'm new to Shopify/ Liquid even though I think this a PHP question but I don't know.

My code was like this (inside the head tag):

```
{{ 'animate.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
```

Does it become like this?

```
 <!-- Defer animate.css-->
  <link rel="preload" href="{{ 'animate.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}" as="style" onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'">
  <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ 'animate.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}"></noscript>
```

Or can I just do it like you would normally in html? Like this:

```
<link rel="preload" href="../assets/animate.css" as="style" onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'">
  <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/animate.css"></noscript>
```

Can you please help or tell me if this is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{{'animate.css' | asset_url }}` is `//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/path/to/your/animate.css`

`{{'animate.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}` is

`<link href="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/path/to/your/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">`

```
<link rel="preload" href="{{'animate.css' | asset_url}}" as="style" onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'">

<noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="{{'animate.css' | asset_url }}"></noscript>
```

Comment: How do i defer it or preload it then in theme.liquid?

Comment: @mohobs Updated the answer, basically the same as George's but his is missing the apostrophe

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add css of preload on shopify, please try like this

```
<link rel="preload" href="{{ 'animate.css' | asset_url  }}" as="style" onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'">
  <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ 'animate.css' | asset_url  }}"></noscript>
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work, returns warning - <link rel=preload> has an invalid `href` value

Comment: @mohobs I have updated the answer. beacuse ' ' was missing